# Rails 3: Detecting types when parsing XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple XML document in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<object>
  <strField>Foo</strField>
  <intField>1</intField>
  <dateField>2010-11-03</dateField>
  <boolField>true</boolField>
  <nilField></nilField>
</object>
```

I would like to parse this into a Hash to be passed to Model.create:

```
{:object => {
  :strField  => 'Foo',
  :intField  => 1,
  :dateField => Date.today,
  :boolField => true,
  :nilField  => nil }}
```

Sadly there are no "type" attributes in the XML, so using Hash.from_xml just parses each field as a string. What I am looking for is some sort of field type auto detection. I have also looked at Nokogiri, but that can't output as a Hash.

What is the simplest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to deal with this would be to build a little pull-parser. Here's the wrong way :-)

# presume xml holds the xml

```
def castValue(node)
  puts "Got #{node.name} with content #{node.content}"
  case node.name
  when "strField"
    return node.content
  when "intField"
    return node.content.to_i
  when "dateField"
    return Date.parse(node.content)
  when "boolField"
    case node.content
    when "true"
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  when "nilField"
    return nil
  end
end


def to_hash xmlstring
  h = {}
  Nokogiri::XML.parse(xmlstring).root.children.each do |node|
    next if node.name == 'text'
    h[node.name] = castValue(node)
  end
  return h
end
```

From there, you just call "h = to_hash myXMLstring" to get the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Rails will automatically convert the strings to their proper types before saving the model. Like when you do: `ModelName.create( params[:model_name] )`

Edit: Unless your hash values aren't individual columns, e.g. you're serializing them.

Answer (score 1):

XML doesn't necessarily have an indicator for the type of the value in a node. You're expected to know that, or your parsing code is, before you get the data. Databases that output XML or spreadsheets often are aware of the type of data, and they'll try to give you some definition of it but there's nothing guaranteeing that what they call their fixed number will match what Ruby calls it. As a result you'll still have to do some sort of attribute matching/mapping to make sense of what they send to you.

If you have a hash it wouldn't be too hard to write code to walk through it and convert the values into the types you expect, or just do it as you consume the values.

I always use Nokogiri to directly parse the XML and then I set the value types as I process the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Either specify it as an attribute in the XML:

```
<intField type="integer">101</intField>
```

Or just use the appropriate conversion method in Ruby, if you know what you're receiving:

```
hash[:strField].to_i
```

There isn't going to be much of a magic way to do it. You could try to analyze what's in the string, but you could easy have a string that's "1/2/1234" which looks like a date but is supposed to be a string.